# Command + N to generate setter and getter the location is adverse in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

In my project, I use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to generate the setter and getter methods.

My code is below:

```
public class Employee {

    private int empId;
    private String empName;
    private Date workDate;
}
```

[image]

But in the end, the setter and getter methods is in adverse order: it become this:

```
public class Employee {

    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    public Date getWorkDate() {
        return workDate;
    }

    public void setWorkDate(Date workDate) {
        this.workDate = workDate;
    }

    private int empId;
    private String empName;
    private Date workDate;

}
```

But I want the getter and setter methods under the properties.

```
public class Employee {

    private int empId;
    private String empName;
    private Date workDate;

    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    public Date getWorkDate() {
        return workDate;
    }

    public void setWorkDate(Date workDate) {
        this.workDate = workDate;
    }
}
```

How to do with it?

Comment: Just cut and paste getters and setters under the properties.

Comment: I believe there must be some settings

Comment: I believe your cursor is before variables and it should be just after declared variables, and then generate getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the getter and setter, your cursor location should be the end of property.

like this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>